# Trading View in Pinescript

Tags: pine-script

Below code showing error:

> Save operation failed, reason: Script could not be translated from: |B|Buytrigger := input(defval=13000.0,

Code:

````
study("Multi Horizontal Lines", overlay=true)
pricedifference = 0.
linesval = 0.
Buytrigger = 0.
Selltrigger = 0.
Buytrigger := input(defval=13000.0, title="Buy Trigger", type=input.float)
Selltrigger := input(defval=13000.0, title="Sell Trigger", type=input.float)
linesval := input(title="How many lines draw above / below", type=input.integer, defval=5)
pricedifference := input(title="Interval", type=input.float, defval=45.0)
line.new(bar_index, Buytrigger, bar_index[75], Buytrigger, width = 1, color=color.green, style=line.style_dashed)
line.new(bar_index, Selltrigger, bar_index[75], Selltrigger, width = 1, color=color.red, style=line.style_dashed)

for i = 1 to linesval
    line.new(bar_index, Buytrigger+(pricedifference*i), bar_index[75], Buytrigger+(pricedifference*i), width = 1, color=color.red)
    line.new(bar_index, Selltrigger-(pricedifference*i), bar_index[75], Selltrigger-(pricedifference*i), width = 1, color=color.green)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script was missing the `//@version=4` line.
That line tells the compiler which Pine version your script is written in.
This will save correctly:

```
//@version=4
study("Multi Horizontal Lines", overlay=true)
pricedifference = 0.
linesval = 0.
Buytrigger = 0.
Selltrigger = 0.
Buytrigger := input(defval=13000.0, title="Buy Trigger", type=input.float)
Selltrigger := input(defval=13000.0, title="Sell Trigger", type=input.float)
linesval := input(title="How many lines draw above / below", type=input.integer, defval=5)
pricedifference := input(title="Interval", type=input.float, defval=45.0)
line.new(bar_index, Buytrigger, bar_index[75], Buytrigger, width = 1, color=color.green, style=line.style_dashed)
line.new(bar_index, Selltrigger, bar_index[75], Selltrigger, width = 1, color=color.red, style=line.style_dashed)

for i = 1 to linesval
    line.new(bar_index, Buytrigger+(pricedifference*i), bar_index[75], Buytrigger+(pricedifference*i), width = 1, color=color.red)
    line.new(bar_index, Selltrigger-(pricedifference*i), bar_index[75], Selltrigger-(pricedifference*i), width = 1, color=color.green)
```